# neo4j, how can search for relationship in this example?

Tags: neo4j

I was learning neo4j, and following the tutorial provide at[searching for relationship](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_create_relationship_without_properties_with_existing_nodes.htm).

I followed it, added two nodes and a relationship between them. I did exactly according to the tutorial in above link. But when i try to display the relationship i just added, by the following

```
  MATCH (e)-[r:DO_SHOPPING_WITH ]->(cc) 
  RETURN r
```

it showed nothing.

to make sure, I displayed all nodes by

```
 MATCH (a) return a
```

and it showed 2 nodes and the relationship between them.

Not only this case, I tried later examples, by similar search for relationship all are showed empty.

could anyone explain why I cannot display the relationship as it is told in the tutorial?

Pretty simple example, but somehow not working.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just talking about the graph result view. When the only items returned from a query are relationships, they won't show up, as it requires the nodes on either side of a relationship to be returned in order to display.

While this is current behavior, past behavior was able to display the start and end nodes of a relationship even if just relationships were returned, and it's not a bad idea to consider reverting to this previous behavior.

I think [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/347) on the browser project is related.

Comment: Seems it does not display a relationship which has no properties. In later examples, relationships with properties are created and i been able to display them in tables.  is there anyway to make neo4j to display the start  and the end nodes of a relationship with/without properties? so, I could confirm that  I am following tutorial without mistakes.

Comment: You won't be able to view a relationship's start or end nodes in any view except the raw code view (it should at least return the ids of the start and end nodes there, but that's probably not how you want to view this). If you want the start and end nodes, if those were a part of your match, then you can return them like `RETURN e, r, cc`. Otherwise, if you need to get start and end nodes from a relationship somewhere in the middle of your query, `startNode(rel)` and `endNode(rel)` are functions you can use to get them and use them in the query.